# Hibernate mongodb configuration file

Tags: mongodb, hibernate

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider">mongodb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host">127.0.0.1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port">27017</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database">eatery</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database">true</property>


        <mapping class="com.ws.web.models.Reservation" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Does anyone know hoe to configure hibernate for mongodb. Docs says that there is no need of dialect. but i got errors

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at com.ws.web.models.Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all i think your configuration is wrong. The proporties that you used should be placed in persistence.xml file. The example is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-configuration).

The necessary properties with description are [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#_configuring_mongodb)